# Unmarshal map[string]DynamoDBAttributeValue into a struct

Tags: go, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-go

I'm trying to set-up an AWS-lambda using [aws-sdk-go](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go) that is triggered whenever a new `user` is added to a certain [dynamodb](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb) table.

Everything is working just fine but I can't find a way to unmarshal a map `map[string]DynamoDBAttributeValue` like:

```
{
    "name": {
        "S" : "John"
    },
    "residence_address": {
        "M": {
            "address": {
                "S": "some place"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To a given struct, for instance, a `User` struct. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-go/api/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute/#example_Unmarshal) is shown an example of unsmarhaling a `map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue` into a given interface, but I can't find a way to do the same thing with `map[string]DynamoDBAttributeValue` even though these types seem to fit the same purposes.

`map[string]DynamoDBAttributeValue` is returned by a `events.DynamoDBEvents` from package `github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events`. This is my code:

```
package handler

import (
    "context"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
)

func HandleDynamoDBRequest(ctx context.Context, e events.DynamoDBEvent) {

    for _, record := range e.Records {

        if record.EventName == "INSERT" {

            // User Struct
            var dynamoUser model.DynamoDBUser

            // Of course this can't be done for incompatible types
            _ := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(record.Change.NewImage, &dynamoUser)
        }

    }

}
```

Of course, I can marshal `record.Change.NewImage` to JSON and unmarshal it back to a given struct, but then, I would have to manually initialize `dynamoUser` attributes starting from the latter ones.

Or I could even write a function that parses `map[string]DynamoDBAttributeValue` to `map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue` like:

```
func getAttributeValueMapFromDynamoDBStreamRecord(e events.DynamoDBStreamRecord) map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue {
    image := e.NewImage
    m := make(map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue)
    for k, v := range image {
        if v.DataType() == events.DataTypeString {
            s := v.String()
            m[k] = &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                S : &s,
            }
        }
        if v.DataType() == events.DataTypeBoolean {
            b := v.Boolean()
            m[k] = &dynamodb.AttributeValue{
                BOOL : &b,
            }
        }
        // . . .
        if v.DataType() == events.DataTypeMap {
            // ?
        }
    }
    return m
}
```

And then simply use `dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap`, but on `events.DataTypeMap` it would be quite a tricky process.

**Is there a way through which I can unmarshal a DynamoDB record coming from a `events.DynamoDBEvent` into a struct with a similar method shown for `map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue`?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I tried the function you provided, and I met some problems with `events.DataTypeList`, so I managed to write the following function that does the trick:

```
// UnmarshalStreamImage converts events.DynamoDBAttributeValue to struct
func UnmarshalStreamImage(attribute map[string]events.DynamoDBAttributeValue, out interface{}) error {

    dbAttrMap := make(map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue)

    for k, v := range attribute {

        var dbAttr dynamodb.AttributeValue

        bytes, marshalErr := v.MarshalJSON(); if marshalErr != nil {
            return marshalErr
        }

        json.Unmarshal(bytes, &dbAttr)
        dbAttrMap[k] = &dbAttr
    }

    return dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(dbAttrMap, out)

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tomorrow I'll try it. About lists you are right, in the example I did not cover them but It's possible to extend my function to handle them. Anyway your solution is by far better than mine.

Comment: I tried your function and it works perfectly. I made small fixes to it since `dbAttrMap` was badly declared and you made no error handling for `marshalErr`. As soon as you accept the edit I'll accept the answer.

Comment: It's better now, approve it.

Answer (score 15):

I was frustrated that the type of NewImage from the record wasn't map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue so I could use the dynamodbattribute package.

The JSON representation of events.DynamoDBAttributeValue seems to be the same as the JSON represenation of dynamodb.AttributeValue.

So I tried creating my own DynamoDBEvent type and changed the type of OldImage and NewImage, so it would be marshalled into map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue instead of map[string]events.DynamoDBAttributeValue

It is a little bit ugly but it works for me.

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/dynamodb/dynamodbattribute"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    lambda.Start(lambdaHandler)
}

// changed type of event from: events.DynamoDBEvent to DynamoDBEvent (see below)
func lambdaHandler(event DynamoDBEvent) error {

    for _, record := range event.Records {

        change := record.Change
        newImage := change.NewImage // now of type: map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue

        var item IdOnly
        err := dynamodbattribute.UnmarshalMap(newImage, &item)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        fmt.Println(item.Id)
    }

    return nil
}

type IdOnly struct {
    Id string `json:"id"`
}

type DynamoDBEvent struct {
    Records []DynamoDBEventRecord `json:"Records"`
}

type DynamoDBEventRecord struct {
    AWSRegion      string                       `json:"awsRegion"`
    Change         DynamoDBStreamRecord         `json:"dynamodb"`
    EventID        string                       `json:"eventID"`
    EventName      string                       `json:"eventName"`
    EventSource    string                       `json:"eventSource"`
    EventVersion   string                       `json:"eventVersion"`
    EventSourceArn string                       `json:"eventSourceARN"`
    UserIdentity   *events.DynamoDBUserIdentity `json:"userIdentity,omitempty"`
}

type DynamoDBStreamRecord struct {
    ApproximateCreationDateTime events.SecondsEpochTime             `json:"ApproximateCreationDateTime,omitempty"`
    // changed to map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue
    Keys                        map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue `json:"Keys,omitempty"`
    // changed to map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue
    NewImage                    map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue `json:"NewImage,omitempty"`
    // changed to map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue
    OldImage                    map[string]*dynamodb.AttributeValue `json:"OldImage,omitempty"`
    SequenceNumber              string                              `json:"SequenceNumber"`
    SizeBytes                   int64                               `json:"SizeBytes"`
    StreamViewType              string                              `json:"StreamViewType"`
}
```

Comment: This is an elegant solution. I like this.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the same problem and the solution is to perform a simple conversion of types. This is possible because in the end the type received by lambda events `events.DynamoDBAttributeValue` and the type used by the SDK V2 of AWS DynamoDB `types.AttributeValue` are the same. Next I show you the conversion code.

```golang
package aws_lambda

import (
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/feature/dynamodb/attributevalue"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go-v2/service/dynamodb/types"
)

func UnmarshalDynamoEventsMap(
    record map[string]events.DynamoDBAttributeValue, out interface{}) error {
    asTypesMap := DynamoDbEventsMapToTypesMap(record)
    err := attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(asTypesMap, out)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func DynamoDbEventsMapToTypesMap(
    record map[string]events.DynamoDBAttributeValue) map[string]types.AttributeValue {
    resultMap := make(map[string]types.AttributeValue)
    for key, rec := range record {
        resultMap[key] = DynamoDbEventsToTypes(rec)
    }
    return resultMap
}

// DynamoDbEventsToTypes relates the dynamo event received by AWS Lambda with the data type that is
// used in the Amazon SDK V2 to deal with DynamoDB data.
// This function is necessary because Amazon does not provide any kind of solution to make this
// relationship between types of data.
func DynamoDbEventsToTypes(record events.DynamoDBAttributeValue) types.AttributeValue {
    var val types.AttributeValue

    switch record.DataType() {
    case events.DataTypeBinary:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberB{
            Value: record.Binary(),
        }
    case events.DataTypeBinarySet:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberBS{
            Value: record.BinarySet(),
        }
    case events.DataTypeBoolean:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberBOOL{
            Value: record.Boolean(),
        }
    case events.DataTypeList:
        var items []types.AttributeValue
        for _, value := range record.List() {
            items = append(items, DynamoDbEventsToTypes(value))
        }
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberL{
            Value: items,
        }
    case events.DataTypeMap:
        items := make(map[string]types.AttributeValue)
        for k, v := range record.Map() {
            items[k] = DynamoDbEventsToTypes(v)
        }
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberM{
            Value: items,
        }
    case events.DataTypeNull:
        val = nil
    case events.DataTypeNumber:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberN{
            Value: record.Number(),
        }
    case events.DataTypeNumberSet:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberNS{
            Value: record.NumberSet(),
        }
    case events.DataTypeString:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberS{
            Value: record.String(),
        }
    case events.DataTypeStringSet:
        val = &types.AttributeValueMemberSS{
            Value: record.StringSet(),
        }
    }

    return val
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a package that allows conversion from events.DynamoDBAttributeValue to dynamodb.AttributeValue

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/aereal/go-dynamodb-attribute-conversions/v2

From there one can unmarshal AttributeValue into struct

```
func Unmarshal(attribute map[string]events.DynamoDBAttributeValue, out interface{}) error {

    av := ddbconversions.AttributeValueMapFrom(attribute)

    return attributevalue.UnmarshalMap(av, out)
}
```